# bi-objective mixed integer linear programming (MILP) problem

Tags: mixed-integer-programming

I have a bi-objective mixed integer linear programming (MILP) problem, which contains two specially sub-objective functions. The first linear objective function, only contains integer variables, while the second one only has continuous variables. In general, such a MILP problem could be solved directly by the solver.
However, recently, I discovered that my MILP problem can be solved in two steps. Firstly, the optimal integer variables can be solved directly by solving a sub-problem that contains the first sub-objective function and constraints related to integer variables. Then, with the obtained integer variables, the MILP problem could be transformed into a linear program problem and find the optimal continuous variables. In this way, the obtained optimal solutions (integer variables and continuous variables) are the same as the way to solve the MILP problem directly.
Is there some feasible way for me to prove that this phenomenon is true?

Comment: This sounds more like one objective with two parts, in which case the approach you describe of partitioning into an ILP and an LP is the basis of (classical) *Benders decomposition*.

Comment: How are your two objectives combined in the full problem? Are they added together to get a single objective function, or are they handled lexicographically (optimize the first objective, then optimize the second subject to not doing worse than optimal on the first)?

Comment: Could you share the problem formulation? The answer to your question depends on the structure of the model.